# Moment.js round dates up

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

In my javascript the library Moment.js rounds my dates up.

```
 Date: 2015-02-09T23:00:00.000Z

 moment(Date).format('DD/MM'); ==> Becomes 10/02
```

I want 09/02 as result. Is there a possible way that the library not rounds the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below.

```
moment(Date,['YYYY-MM-DD']).format('DD/MM');
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely one of timezones: by default, momentjs parses your string and converts it to your local timezone. If I see this correctly, the 'Z' in your date signifies zulu - or UTC time. If your timezone is +02:00 for example, that would make it the 10th, 01:00.

Use [`Moment#utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)

```
moment(Date).utc().format('DD/MM');
```

to output format the date as UTC again.

Answer (score 1):

Moment.js will output dates in the local time zone, so it might very well be that it's caused by a difference in timezones.

If you want to show the date/time as encoded into the original string, use `parseZone` like this:

```
var dateStr = "2015-02-09T23:00:00.000Z";
moment.parseZone(dateStr).format('DD/MM');
```