# MomentJS .date() issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Could anyone please explain me why `moment("2013-04-22 00:00:00+07:00").date()` returns `21`?

For example `moment("2013-04-22 00:00:00+02:00").date()` returns `22`.

I would be interested in getting the date without taking into account any timezone info in the string from which the moment object is built, i.e. always 22 in this particular example.

Comment: Are you using an older version?  I just tested both of those strings and the return was 21 for both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moment.js round dates up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612525/moment-js-round-dates-up)

Comment: I think I figured it out, chazsolo see my answer below why this returns 21 for both in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out: `moment("iso8601_string")` parses/converts that string into a local time. In my case, I'm in the UTC+2 timezone, so parsing strings containing `"+02:00"` (or `"+01:00"`) and then calling `.date()` returns 22 because the time stored in the moment object matches my local time.

However, when parsing a string with e.g. `"+07:00"`, the time stored in the moment object will be my local time, in which case the date will actually be different, a day before.

I think also my original requirement was convoluted and based on an incorrect assumption. My use-case was that I got the datetime from some UI widget always as date+time, but I needed only the date. Writing a unit test which parsed a string containing `"+07:00"` caused the date to be "incorrect". However this was an incorrect assumption, because (at least in my use-case) the datetime from the UI widget will always be in the local time so the code won't ever parse a string containing `"+07:00"`.

I'm not sure that a use-case as I originally stated does exist in the real world:

- you get a string containing a date in another timezone
- you need to take the date out of it, but in the timezone of that date (why?)

I guess normally whenever getting a date from somewhere remote the convention is to always get UTC, that way the point of reference is clear and you can convert it further locally. So probably the case when you get a date in a random timezone and need the date from it, in that timezone, isn't common. Still, as an academic question, I don't know how I would be able to get the date out of it in that case :)

Comment: Use `parseZone` to create a moment object that remains in the timezone it was given and is not converted to your local time: `moment.parseZone("2013-04-22 00:00:00+07:00").get("date")`

Comment: Good one, thanks! Will not use it in my case as its redundant, but could be useful to someobody.